# Getting the a child class defined as the parent class to output the child function

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-instances

I have a class defined like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
protected:
    float width, height;
public:
    virtual ~Shape(){}

    void set_data (float a, float b){
        width = a;
        height = b;
    }

    virtual string getType() {
        return "Shapes";
    }
};

class Polygon: public Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Polygon(){};

    virtual string getType() {
        return "Polygon";
    }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
    public:
        virtual ~Triangle(){};

    virtual string getType() {
        return "Triangle";
    }
};
```

And I want to get a program that uses this class

```
int main () {
    Shape poly = Polygon();
    Shape tri = Triangle();
    std::cout << poly.getType() << std::endl;
    std::cout << tri.getType() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get `poly.getType()` to print out `Polygon`, for example? Right now it is printing out `Shapes`. I know if I did

```
Polygon poly = Polygon()
```

that does the trick, but I want to store `poly` as a `Shape` object, construct it using a `Polygon` constructor, and ensure that

```
poly.getType()
```

returns `Polygon`, not `Shapes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism only works with non-value types; i.e. with references and pointers. And since references must be immediately bound they are not much use here.

Your best bet is to use `std::unique_ptr<Shape> poly(new Polygon());` and call using

`poly->getType();`

I'm using `std::unique_ptr` so I don't need to call `delete` explicitly. `std::shared_ptr` would work too but do consult the documentation so you use the one most appropriate to your use case.

By the way, you don't need to repeat `virtual` when overriding the function in child classes. You only need to mark the function `virtual` in the base class.

Comment: Do make sure you read the docs on `unique_ptr` though if you choose to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code suffers from [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c). Use:

```
int main () {
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> poly = new Polygon();
    std::unique_ptr<Shape> tri = new Triangle();
    std::cout << poly->getType() << std::endl;
    std::cout << tri->getType() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. Will accept once stack overflow allows me to

Comment: Cute (+1) but if `getType()` were to throw an exception, you'll leak memory.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I'm trying to get in the habit of using `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` whenever it's appropriate. Old habits.

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable String type. Set it in each instantiable subclass. Have a function getType in Shape that returns it.

Answer (score 0):

That answer above was basically right: "I need to use pointers" is the key.

This solved my problem:

```
int main ()
{
    Polygon poly = Polygon();
    Shape* testing = &poly;
    std::cout << testing->getType() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I will accept your answer in about an hour's time because Stack overflow makes me wait for a while before accepting. Thanks